# Is it possible to generate HTML cod inside a variable and then echo it in WordPress ( escape problem )

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

This is my code:

```
public function settings_inline_style_callback() {
    $type = esc_html( $this->options['inline_style'] );
    $temp0 = '<input type="radio" name="My_options[inline_style]" id="inline_style_';
    $temp1 = '<label for="inline_style_';   
    $html = $temp0 . '0" value="0" ' . checked( $type, '0', false ) . ' />';
    $html .= $temp1 . '0">External CSS style</label><br />';
    $html .= $temp0 . '1" value="1" ' . checked( $type, '1', false ) . ' />';
    $html .= $temp1 . '1">Inline CSS style</label>';
    echo $html;
}
```

The WordPress plugin review team said the escape was not done properly. They said you have to escape WHEN you echo. Not when you save to the variable. (in this line: echo $html;)

I am new to WordPress and PHP. I do not understand the problem with this code.
How should I modify this code?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You've shown a form field for selecting CSS style option. But you haven't show where you input and output the option "inline_style". Where and how do you do those? Also where and how do you load `My_option[inline_style]`?

Comment: This function is a callback for add_settings_field() function, and options['inline_style'] load in add_options_page() function callback.

Answer (score 0):

So this is because the `esc_html` function only works when running during echo. Below is a way you can do your code.

```
printf(
    '<input type="radio" name="My_options[inline_style]" id="inline_style_0" value="0" %s/>
    <label for="inline_style_0">External CSS style</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="My_options[inline_style]" id="inline_style_1" value="1" %s/>
    <label for="inline_style_1">Inline CSS style</label>',
    checked(esc_html($this->options['inline_style']), '0', false),
    checked(esc_html($this->options['inline_style']), '1', false),
);
```